# Replace new line character between double quotes with space

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, awk

i want to read a data row by row and whereever i find double quote i want to replace new line character with a space till the second double quote encounter
like

```
090033ec82b13639,CPDM Initiated,Logistical,"There corrected.",Gul Y Serbest,Urology
090033ec82ae0c07,Initiated,NA,"To   local testing
Rohit  3 to 4.",Julienne B Orr,Oncology
090033ec82b35fd0,Externally Initiated,NA,regulatory agency requests,Kenneth A Lord,Oncology
```

Like in above data second row as it finds the double quote(open) and close double quote in 3rd line so we need to merge these lines by a single space as below:

```
090033ec82b13639,CPDM Initiated,Logistical,"There corrected.",Gul Y Serbest,Urology
090033ec82ae0c07,Initiated,NA,"To   local testing Rohit  3 to 4.",Julienne B Orr,Oncology
090033ec82b35fd0,Externally Initiated,NA,regulatory agency requests,Kenneth A Lord,Oncology
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this **gnu-awk one-liner**:

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n/, " ", RT); print $0  RT}' file
090033ec82b13639,CPDM Initiated,Logistical,"There corrected.",Gul Y Serbest,Urology
090033ec82ae0c07,Initiated,NA,"To   local testing Rohit  3 to 4.",Julienne B Orr,Oncology
090033ec82b35fd0,Externally Initiated,NA,regulatory agency requests,Kenneth A Lord,Oncology
```

- `RS='"[^"]*"'` - Input Record Separator is set to regex `'"[^"]*"'`
- `-v ORS=` - Output Record Separator is set to null
- `gsub(/\n/, " ", RT)` - Replace newlines with space in the text matched by `Input Record Separator`

---

And here is a **perl one-liner**:

```
perl -0pe 's/"[^\n"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|("[^"\n]*)\n([^"]*")/$1 $2/g' file
090033ec82b13639,CPDM Initiated,Logistical,"There corrected.",Gul Y Serbest,Urology
090033ec82ae0c07,Initiated,NA,"To   local testing Rohit  3 to 4.",Julienne B Orr,Oncology
090033ec82b35fd0,Externally Initiated,NA,regulatory agency requests,Kenneth A Lord,Oncology
```

Comment: I've heard about `perl` verb pattern before, but never actually used it myself +1

Answer (score 4):

This will work for the simple case in your example:

```
$ perl -00pe 's/(\n[^"]*"[^"]+)\n(.+?")/$1 $2/gm' file 
090033ec82b13639,CPDM Initiated,Logistical,"There corrected.",Gul Y Serbest,Urology
090033ec82ae0c07,Initiated,NA,"To   local testing Rohit  3 to 4.",Julienne B Orr,Oncology
090033ec82b35fd0,Externally Initiated,NA,regulatory agency requests,Kenneth A Lord,Oncology
```

#### Caveats

- This will load the entire file into memory and that might be a problem, depending on the size of the file.
- It doesn't deal with open quotes spanning more than a single line.

#### Explanation

- `-00` : slurp the file, treat it as a single string.
- `-pe` : print each input line (a single "line" here, because of the `-00`) after applying the script given by `-e` to it.
- `(\n[^"]*"[^"]+)\n(.+?")` : match a newline (used to indicate the start of a line), followed by as many non-`"` as possible (`[^"]*`), then a `"`, followed by only non-`"` characters until the next newline (`[^"]+\n`) and then everything until the 1st quote. The parentheses are there so we can capture the strings matched.
- `$1 $2` : This is the replacement, it will print the first two captured groups so we replace the matched pattern with the 1st group, a space and then the second.
- `gm` : the `g` makes the replacement global, and the `m` allows multiline strings.

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner will do:

```
perl -F'' -0 -ane ' foreach $char(@F){  $char eq q(") && {$seen= $seen ? 0 : 1}; $seen  && $char eq "\n" && { $char=" "}; print $char}'
```

or:

```
perl -F'' -0 -ane 'map {$_ eq q(") && {$seen=$seen?0:1}; $seen && $_ eq "\n" &&{$_=" "}; print} @F'
```

In action:

```
$ perl -F'' -0 -ane ' foreach $char(@F){  $char eq q(") && {$seen= $seen ? 0 : 1}; $seen  && $char eq "\n" && { $char=" "}; print $char}' file
090033ec82b13639,CPDM Initiated,Logistical,"There corrected.",Gul Y Serbest,Urology
090033ec82ae0c07,Initiated,NA,"To   local testing Rohit  3 to 4.",Julienne B Orr,Oncology
090033ec82b35fd0,Externally Initiated,NA,regulatory agency requests,Kenneth A Lord,Oncology
```

Comment: Output should be 3 rows not 2

Comment: I also provided a `perl one-liner` in my answer which is purely based on regex.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Text::CSV;
my $csv = 'Text::CSV'->new({ binary => 1,
                             eol => "\n",
                           })
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . 'Text::CSV'->error_diag;

open my $CSV, '<:utf8', shift or die $!;
while (my $row = $csv->getline($CSV)) {
    s/\n/ /g for @$row;
    $csv->print(*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

Gives the expected output when run with

```
remove-newlines.pl input.csv > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

a solution using (I think) bashism (NOT POSIX, it **shouldn't** work on other shell than bash) :

```
function fixmylines { 
  local line fullline
  while read line ; do 
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^[0-9a-f]{16}, ]] ; then
      [ "$fullline" ] && echo "$fullline"
      fullline="$line"
    else
      fullline+=" $line"
    fi
  done
  echo "$fullline"
}
```

then you may pipe your data to this function (" | fixmylines ").

*Note: it use the regexp "^[0-9a-f]{16}," to determine a beginning of a line*